# Type of “id” (number) in user.json is not supported. Use objects or arrays of objects error when using json-server, why?

Tags: angularjs, json, json-server

I am working on an Angular 4 App. 
I am trying to get data from a JSON file for building a user dashboard.

I created a json file and tried loading it using JSON server using this: `$ json-server --watch user.json` and I am getting the following error:

**Type of "id" (number) in user.json is not supported. Use objects or arrays of objects.**.

When I remove the "id" field in the file, I get the same error with "name".

I feel there is something wrong with the way I have created the json files. I am new to web development, so don't mind if it's a very fundamental mistake.

This is my json file:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "name":"Kajal Agarwal",
 "department":"Information Technology",
 "college":"Indian Institute of Engineering Science and Technology, Shibpur",
 "subjects":[
    {
        "title":"Data Structures",
        "active":true,
        "faculty":"Prasun Ghosal",
        "notifications":4,
        "color":"#9c27b0"
    },
    {
        "title":"Operating System",
        "active":true,
        "faculty":"Niharika Singh",
        "notifications":0,
        "color":"#ffc107"
    },
    {
        "title":"Algorithms",
        "active":true,
        "faculty":"Debojit Mondal",
        "notifications":1,
        "color":"#009688"
    },
    {
        "title":"Web Technologies",
        "active":true,
        "faculty":"Shantanu Saurabh",
        "notifications":2,
        "color":"#ff5722"
    },
    {
        "title":"Formal Language and Automata Theory",
        "active":true,
        "faculty":"Sudhanshu Sekhar",
        "notifications":3,
        "color":"#03a9f4"
    },
    {
        "title":"Digital Logic and Circuit Design",
        "active":false,
        "faculty":"",
        "notifications":0,
        "color":"#9e9e9e"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error tells you what to do. **Use objects or arrays of objects**

Id should be object or arrays of objects, same for the rest of the properties.

Maybe you should consider edit your user.json

suggestion:

```
{
    "about" : [{
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Kajal Agarwal",
            "department" : "Information Technology",
            "college" : "Indian Institute of Engineering Science and Technology, Shibpur"
        }
    ],
    "subjects" : [{
            "title" : "Data Structures",
            "active" : true,
            "faculty" : "Prasun Ghosal",
            "notifications" : 4,
            "color" : "#9c27b0"
        }, {
            "title" : "Operating System",
            "active" : true,
            "faculty" : "Niharika Singh",
            "notifications" : 0,
            "color" : "#ffc107"
        }, {
            "title" : "Algorithms",
            "active" : true,
            "faculty" : "Debojit Mondal",
            "notifications" : 1,
            "color" : "#009688"
        }, {
            "title" : "Web Technologies",
            "active" : true,
            "faculty" : "Shantanu Saurabh",
            "notifications" : 2,
            "color" : "#ff5722"
        }, {
            "title" : "Formal Language and Automata Theory",
            "active" : true,
            "faculty" : "Sudhanshu Sekhar",
            "notifications" : 3,
            "color" : "#03a9f4"
        }, {
            "title" : "Digital Logic and Circuit Design",
            "active" : false,
            "faculty" : "",
            "notifications" : 0,
            "color" : "#9e9e9e"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked. However, I still don't understand how this:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1
is a valid json file, while the file I created isn't. They are similar.

Comment: It is a valid json but if you want to use json-server to access to any property of the user.json, that property cannot be a number or a string, it should be an object or array of objects.

Answer (score 22):

Maybe I'm late for the response, but this is just for future readers since I too faced similar problem until I understood more about json-server.

As such there is nothing wrong with your JSON object. The reason why you are getting that error has to do with how json-server works.

**Each and every key directly exposed at the root of the JSON object is considered as a separate URL in json-server**. In your case, if you wrap your entire JSON object inside a key eg: '**data**', your error would be resolved. Your JSON object would look something like below

```
{
"data":{
 "id": 1,
 "name":"Kajal Agarwal",
 "department":"Information Technology",
 "college":"Indian Institute of Engineering Science and Technology, Shibpur",
 "subjects":[
    {
        "title":"Data Structures",
        "active":true,
        "faculty":"Prasun Ghosal",
        "notifications":4,
        "color":"#9c27b0"
    },
    {
        "title":"Operating System",
        "active":true,
        "faculty":"Niharika Singh",
        "notifications":0,
        "color":"#ffc107"
    },
    {
        "title":"Algorithms",
        "active":true,
        "faculty":"Debojit Mondal",
        "notifications":1,
        "color":"#009688"
    },
    {
        "title":"Web Technologies",
        "active":true,
        "faculty":"Shantanu Saurabh",
        "notifications":2,
        "color":"#ff5722"
    },
    {
        "title":"Formal Language and Automata Theory",
        "active":true,
        "faculty":"Sudhanshu Sekhar",
        "notifications":3,
        "color":"#03a9f4"
    },
    {
        "title":"Digital Logic and Circuit Design",
        "active":false,
        "faculty":"",
        "notifications":0,
        "color":"#9e9e9e"
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Now if you try to access the root key from URL like below. You would be able to fetch your entire JSON object.

```
localhost:3000/data
```

If you were to add another key called "**data2**" at the root of the JSON object and assign some other object then you would have another URL as below

```
localhost:3000/data2
```

Hope this makes sense and is helpful.
You could also visit [here](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/create-a-rest-api-with-json-server-36da8680136d) to see an example of how json-server works