# Is it valid json data?(I've tested in the validation site but..)

Tags: json

I'am given data from back-end team from work.
and the data looks like below. (they haven't built real server so gave me mock data)
so I was going to use json-fake server and I got this error
 `Error:Type of "total" (number)  is not supported. Use objects or arrays of objects`
and I thought "oh this data is not valid form I guess" so I tested it on
json data validation site, and it was valid.
according to the error message, this data is not valid isn't it?

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "James"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Paul"
    }
  ],
  "total": 2,
  "status": "alive"
}
```

Comment: That **is** valid JSON. The error message must come from your application code.

Comment: How are you processing this JSON object?

Comment: I just tried to start the fake server by using `json-server --watch db.json` command, and I got this error message

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47628015/6634744

Answer (score 0):

It is syntactically correct JSON. It sounds like there is a semantic or schematic issue with what your programm expects `total` to be.